# Hamiltonian cycle adjacency sum Proof

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let $C$ be a Hamiltonian cycle on a graph with vertices labeled {$1,...,9$}. Prove that there are $3$ vertices adjacent in $C$ whose labels sum to at least $12$.

I understand why this fact is true by drawing a graph and different and calculating the adjacent vertices sum to be at least $12$.

How would I go about proving it? Would I use the definition of a Hamiltonian cycle and how would I show that the vertices have a minimum value of $12$?

Comment: By "$3$ vertices adjacent in $C$" do you mean three vertices $x,y,z$ with both edges $(x,y),(y,z)$ in $C$?

Comment: Yes I believe thats what the question is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $9$ vertex. The minimum sum it can be a part of is $1 + 2 + 9  = 12$.  Hence the sum of the vertices around $9$ (and including it) is always at least $12$.